# Multiple Schema.org markups on a single product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, seo

On a single product page I have two Product types. One has only "name" and "sku" and the other has more properties. Which will Google take into account?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a way to avoid the uncertainty (as Google will most likely never document what they’ll do in such a case, and it could change anytime, or depend on additional signals etc.):

**Give both `Product` items the same URI as ID.** This conveys to consumers that both of the `Product` items are about the same product, not different products. Here is an [example with all three syntaxes (JSON-LD, Microdata, RDFa)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/117586/17633).

(Of course, the ideal solution would be to have only one `Product` item in the first place, but this is often impossible or hard to implement.)

Answer (score 0):

Helpful if you shared the markup.

You can always check to see what Google sees with their structured date testing tool: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

Comment: I have added a screenshot now.